# One word for an exactly opposite situation

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe an exactly opposite situation? In context, if someone describes a situation in which he found himself, and I tell him I found myself in the exactly opposite situation, what word would describe this? Let's assume *irony* may be involved in some way, but that is not the word I am looking for.

Comment: Antithesis? Look up its synonyms, as well.

Comment: An 'antithetical' situation? Incidentally, though people use the term 'exact opposite' I think it ought to be 'exactly opposite', otherwise I would feel a need to hyphenate, as in 'an exact-opposite situation'. But I already hear @Fumble Fingers tut-tutting at this.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear. I'll attempt to clarify it, but if I'm way off base, just let me know. Don

Comment: Why do you think there might be a single word for this?

Comment: how about **"opposite"**?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used the word irony, I am tempted to say that two exactly opposite situations are not ironic; they are coincidental. Perhaps an example would help.

> Frieda: "My dog Willie ran away this week, and I haven't been able to locate him."
>
> Sally to Freida: "Hmmm. I suppose I shouldn't tell you, but just this week I became the owner of a rescue dog from the Humane Society!"

Here are two "exactly opposite situations," but they do not necessarily involve irony, just an unfortunate coincidence. One situation is sad; the other is joyful. One person lost a dog, and the other person "found" a dog.

Perhaps commenters @WS2 and @Kris, above, are on the right track in suggesting that what you describe as "exactly opposite situations" are in some sense "antithetical situations."

Is there a single word besides antithetical, though? That's a tough one. Two words would work just fine, but one word? Not so much! How about

> - a weird coincidence?
> - an incredible coincidence?
> - a surprising coincidence?
> - a sad coincidence?
> - a snafu? (**s** ituation **n** ormal, **a** ll **f** ouled **u** p)
> - bad karma/good karma?
> - bad luck? (A thief steals a hundred times in a row without getting caught, and you, when you impulsively and for the first time in your life pick up a donut in a store and eat it without paying for it, get caught and arrested for shoplifting! Now those two situations are in a sense "opposite" and tinged with irony, especially if you have a reputation for being an upstanding, law-abiding citizen.)

Unless you provide a clearer context for your two "opposite situations," I'm at a loss as to what to call them, at least in one word.